# Export to excel using OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, openxml

Can we generate an excel document using openXML from a List , but with cutom columns . More like a template . If master excel sheet contains 5 Columns [Column names are Object  Properties ] The export functionality export the mentioned 5 Columns only. If template excel file contains 6 Columns the generated file should only ocntains the 6 columns in the order as in template.
Is this way of generation of excel document is possible using OpenXML or not ?
I usually follow the below code for exel generation , but issue if some one want to remove any columns or change order in generated excel i have to rearrange the code every time

```
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView gridvw = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
             gridvw.DataSource = details.ToList(); //bind the datatable to the gridview
             gridvw.DataBind();
             Response.ClearContent();
             Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", name));
             Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
             Response.BufferOutput = true; 
             StringWriter swr = new StringWriter();
             HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(swr);
             gridvw.RenderControl(tw);
             Response.Write(swr.ToString());
             Response.End();
```